# Make navigation appear side by side on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like the nested lists, that are hidden by default, to appear to the side of the original navigation list. This would look similar to two columns of lists, but the second column will fill itself with the nested lists contents when hovered over a specific list element.

I began to work on this problem, but realized I didn't really know how using purely CSS, and not physically creating two divs. Here is my code so far, which is heavily flawed.

http://jsfiddle.net/sg6MX/

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
           ...
```

Comment: I recently made this fiddle, it may help you: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/PrSUL/

Comment: How does this look? http://jsfiddle.net/sg6MX/3/  -- I just also want you to be aware that a hover effect for a desktop is really cool but it won't work for a mobile device.. in which case you should use a media query to switch it to an onclick event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need javascript for show sublist, use CSS3 =)

Code: `http://jsfiddle.net/sg6MX/2/`

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

nav li ul:hover {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But it seems to extend from the point where the first list element is, instead of from the top of the navigation menu. How would you make it to where it is visually similar to having two divs of text next to each other?

Comment: Also, when I go to click one of the nested list items, it goes away because the other element is no longer being hovered over. How would I fix this?

Comment: That fixes the hover issue, make the top of the nested lists' text the same as the original navigation's text.

Comment: With this style, usability can get worse, it is good to improve the style first.
Depends menu, better stay next to LI